# Test multithreaded code in TestNG

Tags: java, multithreading, testng

I have this problem:

```
@Test
public void foo() throws Exception {
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor stpe = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    stpe.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             // does not make this unit test fail :(
             Assert.AssertEquals(1, 2);
       }
    });
}
```

How do I get those exceptions to fail my test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `submit()` method returns a `Future<?>`. If you try to get the result of the Future, the method will throw the Throwable that has been thrown inside the `Runnable`:

```
Future<?> future = stpe.submit( .... 

future.get(); // this call will throw the exception that has been thrown in the Runnable.
```

This way, exceptions/errors in the run method will make the test fail.

Comment: This is correct but doesn't solve my actual situation in which I don't control the thread pool, I improperly distilled it.  So I'll accept this and post another ?.

Comment: You mean you don't control the code where the submit method is called, so you can't get the Future<?> object? I guess another question with more details would be good, yes.

Comment: here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170055/failing-testng-unit-test-from-a-callback-i-dont-own-in-my-code