# TestNG fail a unit test without throwing an exception

Tags: java, maven, testng, surefire

This may be a solution to my other problem: [Test multithreaded code in TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169889/test-multithreaded-code-in-testng)

Essentially I need a way to fail test `foo` from some other thread.  That means throwing an exception won't work.  The only hack I can think of is to add a poll that keeps waiting for an exception but I can think of plenty of problems for this:

- must duplicate this in each test
- how long to poll for?  need to configure right, could force tests to take too long

  Is this possible in TestNG?

Also using Maven's Surefire plugin in case that is relevant.  (I'm still learning what each of these technologies handles).

Comment: To clarify, you want to run an asynchronous test, where the test finishes some time after the method returns, and will run on other threads.