# Failing TestNG unit test from a callback I don't own in my code

Tags: java, testng, surefire

I [previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15169889/1339987) how to fail a unit test from a thread pool.

```
@Test
public void foo() throws Exception {
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor stpe = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    stpe.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             // does not make this unit test fail :(
             Assert.AssertEquals(1, 2);
       }
    });
}
```

The solution I accepted was to block on the returned `Future` and get.  But in my actual setting I own neither the threadpool nor the submit call - it's a callback that ultimately originates from MINA.

About the best idea I have is messing around with the global default exception handler but seems very kludgy.

Maven surefire if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same question, and my question is here: [TestNG Make assert in multithread way (not run in multithread)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516022/testng-make-assert-in-multithread-way-not-run-in-multithread)

and here's my solution:

As java pass method's parameter by reference, so I wrote a ResultWrapper class

```
public class ResultWrapper {

    boolean result;

    public boolean getResult()
    {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(boolean result)
    {
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

Instead of making any assert in `public void run()` I put the result into ResultWrapper: `resultWrapper.setResult(actual == expectedAssert);`

(the ResultWrapper is pass to the class which call the Runnable class in Constructor)

And I make assert outSide in test method like this:

@Test

```
public void assign_assign_release_release() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, InterruptedException{

        assignUntilSuccess();
        releaseUntilSuccessAndExpect(1);
        Assert.assertTrue(resultWrapper.getResult());
    }
```

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Oh, and try this solution here: http://eyalsch.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/multithreaded-tests/