# TestNG Make assert in multithread way (not run in multithread)

Tags: java, multithreading, testng

My problem is I need to call method in a multiThread way, such as

```
@Test
public void assignInMutiThread()
{
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new AssignAndExpect(0));
    thread1.start();
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new AssignAndExpect(1));
    thread2.start();
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
}
```

Thread will send a http request and check if the response equals to expect. As I need to override the `public void run()` method, I can not return the response code to the test method.

```
public class AssignExecuteAndAssert implements Runnable{

    int expectedAssert = 0;

    public AssignExecuteAndAssert(int expectedAssert)
    {
        this.expectedAssert = expectedAssert;
    }

    public void run() {
        HttpGet assign1 = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8707/assign?uuid="+(new Random().nextInt(99999)));
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(assign1);
        InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        int resoponseStatus = inputStream.read();
        Assert.assertEquals(resoponseStatus, expectedAssert);
    }
}
```

And the problem is whatever the Assert is right or wrong, this test method is always passed.
Is there any way to make test fail if the assert in thread fail?

I find the similar question here: [Failing TestNG unit test from a callback I don't own in my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170055/failing-testng-unit-test-from-a-callback-i-dont-own-in-my-code) but there is no answer.

And suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks!